# PNP biasing logic resistor configuration

Tags: pnp

I have a PNP transistor connected as follows.
I know that there is voltage divider between Vdd and Vin.

What is the logic behind this configuration of PNP?
What kind of state it tries to bias it into?
UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: Where  did you find this circuit? It won't do anything useful; any voltage significantly less than Vdd on the input will just short out Vdd.

Comment: The PNP is wrongly connected, and the circuit is not helpful in anything, besides testing the reverse Vbe breakdown voltage. I suggest reading again some basic text on bipolar transistors.

Comment: Hello , I had a mistake.
The circuit is updated.

Comment: @lub2354 It still does the same thing I said in the first place, just with the transistor in forward active instead of reverse active mode.

Comment: Where is the circuit output (where to connect the load)?

Comment: Hello, I have built the circuit attached bellow.My goal is to switch it into saturated state.
for forward active PNP we need the Emitter-base forward biased and base-collector reversed biased.
(emitter)P-N(base) needs to be V_E>V_B to forward biased.
(base)N-P(collector) reversed biased V_base>V_collector.

I think its in active state.How do i improve my circuit co i could switch it between saturation and active?
Thanks.

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/11478/ONSEMI/2N5087.html

https://ibb.co/0DpWMFM